# Understanding Matlab syntax

Tags: matlab, syntax

I'm currently working on one mathematical algorithm on C, but I found a realization on matlab. The problem is that I don't know syntax. Can anybody explain me whats the meaning of this code?

```
[data(:,nt)'; zeros(nz-1,nx)]
```

`nz`, `nx`, `nt` are integers and data is a `nx` x `nt` matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data(:,nt)` means all rows (`:`) of column `nt` of the `data` matrix. The apostrophe (`'`) means *take the transpose of that*.

`zeros(nz-1,nx)` means a matrix filled with zeros of size `nz-1` x `nx`.

The `[ ... ; ...]` construct means *vertical concatenation* of the two matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Simon did most of the explaining, but remember that `nt` might be a matrix. Say `nt = [1 2 3 1]`. This would return columns 1, 2, 3 and 1 (anew), concatenated horizontally.

Comment: True in general but the OP did say that `data` is a `nx` by `nt` matrix which implies that `nt` is a scalar and which also implies that `data(:,nt)` could have also been written `data(:,end)`.